# Wi-Fi connected but no Internet - Lenovo B590

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, lenovo, connection

I just install a ubuntu on a Lenovo B590. My problem is that a can connect my laptop on wifi but I have no internet connexion.

I found some tricks to do like to shutdown the IPV6, but it doesn't work. I already done all the apt upgrade and apt update.

So now I'm connected with the ethernet wire, and I have turned off my wifi in order to get internet and post my question.

So there are some info about my setup:

```
ifcongig -a
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.97  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::672:e2fc:a446:9acc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:97:0e:63:eb:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26490  bytes 20526646 (20.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24330  bytes 3114601 (3.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 4494  bytes 396841 (396.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4494  bytes 396841 (396.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0b1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 68:94:23:f1:40:6d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3558  bytes 941188 (941.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3426  bytes 398888 (398.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0608]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

Here  the full info about my setup:

[INFO ABOUT MY SETUP WITH WIRELESS INFO SCRITP](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/N5rKFbW5bd/)

Tell me what additional info do you need in order to help me?

So I run 
    `sudo dmesg -l err`

```
[    0.043076] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECOR] (        (ptrval)) [EmbeddedControl] (20170831/evregion-166)
[    0.043083] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20170831/exfldio-299)
[    0.043101] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._REG, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550)
[    1.195383] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECRM] (        (ptrval)) [EmbeddedControl] (20170831/evregion-166)
[    1.195390] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20170831/exfldio-299)
[    1.195412] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.MDEC, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550)
[    1.195421] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.TZS0._SCP, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550)
[   87.304365] acer_wmi: Unsupported machine has AMW0_GUID1, unable to load
[   97.884514] Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1
[  207.897746] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[  207.897765] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[  209.480318] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[  209.480322] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[  211.075444] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[  484.393177] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[  484.393198] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[  484.393205] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[  604.032008] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[  604.032013] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[  607.394942] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[  734.451187] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[  734.451206] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[  734.451213] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[  736.440126] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[  736.440132] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[  739.346221] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[ 1596.081850] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[ 1596.081869] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[ 1596.081876] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[ 5814.647472] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[ 5814.647522] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[ 5815.697842] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[ 5815.697849] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
michel@michel-Lenovo-B590:~$ b43.allhwsupport=1
b43.allhwsupport=1 : commande introuvable
```

I restart my computer and re-run
    `sudo dmesg -l err`

```
> [    0.043062] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECOR] (       
> (ptrval)) [EmbeddedControl] (20170831/evregion-166) [    0.043069]
> ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler
> (20170831/exfldio-299) [    0.043087] ACPI Error: Method
> parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._REG, AE_NOT_EXIST
> (20170831/psparse-550) [    1.195470] ACPI Error: No handler for
> Region [ECRM] (        (ptrval)) [EmbeddedControl]
> (20170831/evregion-166) [    1.195477] ACPI Error: Region
> EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20170831/exfldio-299) [   
> 1.195500] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.MDEC, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550) [    1.195508] ACPI Error: Method
> parse/execution failed \_TZ.TZS0._SCP, AE_NOT_EXIST
> (20170831/psparse-550) [   62.156126] acer_wmi: Unsupported machine
> has AMW0_GUID1, unable to load [   63.459763] Support for cores
> revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try
> b43.allhwsupport=1 [   77.374925] brcmsmac bcma0:1:
> brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement) [  
> 77.374939] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement) [   78.665821] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac:
> brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated [   78.665825] brcmsmac
> bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement) [ 
> 124.759199] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated [  124.759206] brcmsmac bcma0:1:
> brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement) [ 
> 125.416663] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated [  125.416668] brcmsmac bcma0:1:
> brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
```

One of you told me that is about the conflict between two driver, so I followed the instructions

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

there is the result

```
`sudo dmesg -l err`

> [    0.037754] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECOR] (       
> (ptrval)) [EmbeddedControl] (20170831/evregion-166) [    0.037761]
> ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler
> (20170831/exfldio-299) [    0.037780] ACPI Error: Method
> parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._REG, AE_NOT_EXIST
> (20170831/psparse-550) [    1.192049] ACPI Error: No handler for
> Region [ECRM] (        (ptrval)) [EmbeddedControl]
> (20170831/evregion-166) [    1.192055] ACPI Error: Region
> EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20170831/exfldio-299) [   
> 1.192078] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.MDEC, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550) [    1.192087] ACPI Error: Method
> parse/execution failed \_TZ.TZS0._SCP, AE_NOT_EXIST
> (20170831/psparse-550) [   61.423633] acer_wmi: Unsupported machine
> has AMW0_GUID1, unable to load [   76.920680] brcmsmac bcma0:1:
> brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement) [  
> 76.920693] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement) [   78.261816] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac:
> brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated [   78.261823] brcmsmac
> bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement) [  
> 79.873522] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
```

There is my result of iwconfig

```
iwconfig
enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0b1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"SFR_31B0"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: E4:5D:51:7F:31:B6   
          Bit Rate=6.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-14 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:18  Invalid misc:52   Missed beacon:
```

0

There is the result of my ping

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=60.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=54.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=51.4 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 51.422/55.376/60.591/3.857 ms
```

Comment: try to see if have any errors on boot time with "sudo dmesg -l err" could be a missing firmware for the device

Comment: Ok, try to fix them first, if you need help with errors showed adds them by edit you question

Comment: Fisrt of all thank you for your consideration, but I dont know what to do with these results. I edit my post in order to make it visible for you.

Comment: Yes, I wrote you an answer a couple of seconds a go (probably when you write the comment) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this package firmware-brcm80211 via apt or you can try to install it by the additional driver (a descriptive procedure here: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/drivers)

by the way just press the super-key (windows key) then type "additional driver" and follow the guided procedure, that should fix it.

Comment: I run sudo apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-brcm80211 then sudo dmesg -l err and I still have same errors

Comment: dmesg are messages from the boot time, so if you want to see the effect you have to restart you computer [edit] says dmesg are error from boot time is reductive.

Answer (score 0):

Try if you can restart network manager  with : `service network-manager restart`
and after that test in terminal with : `ping www.google.com`

Comment: This is the resullt of that you ask me to do

PING www.google.com (172.217.18.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ham02s14-in-f196.1e100.net (172.217.18.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=60.4 ms
...
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
50 packets transmitted, 30 received, 40% packet loss, time 49381ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 54.304/93.639/416.632/87.150 ms

Answer (score 0):

We notice this in your paste:

```
b43                   413696  0
mac80211              778240  2 b43,brcmsmac
cfg80211              622592  3 b43,mac80211,brcmsmac
ssb                    57344  1 b43
```

There are two conflicting drivers fighting to control your wireless. I believe the correct driver is *brcmsmac*. Let's blacklist the others. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us hear the result.

Comment: I did that you told me and reboot the laptop. I edit my post to show you the return of `sudo dmesg -l err`

Comment: It appears that you are connected. Please show: `iwconfig` also: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` all with the ethernet detached.

Comment: I run your command and paste the result. Thx all for your help and consideration